# Stored procedure to subtract from column with same dates

Tags: mysql

I have the following columns:

```
2022-05-25T17:31:34+0000    92  7   1
2022-05-25T16:06:46+0000    50  5   9
2022-05-25T13:05:27+0000    91  10  106
2022-05-25T09:17:01+0000    48  4   4
2022-05-25T08:43:05+0000    60  4   2
2022-05-25T06:26:38+0000    24  3   6
2022-05-24T15:14:49+0000    55  12  6
2022-05-24T12:25:35+0000    43  8   2
2022-05-24T11:15:24+0000    66  7   2
2022-05-24T10:45:56+0000    37  15  2
2022-05-23T17:51:09+0000    59  7   1
2022-05-23T17:50:44+0000    47  6   3
2022-05-23T15:48:02+0000    126 7   13
2022-05-23T11:42:26+0000    64  9   9
2022-05-27T06:00:29+0000    3   0   1
2022-05-25T17:31:34+0000    96  7   1
2022-05-25T16:06:46+0000    55  5   9
2022-05-25T13:05:27+0000    99  11  116
2022-05-25T09:17:01+0000    52  4   15
2022-05-25T08:43:05+0000    61  4   2
2022-05-25T06:26:38+0000    26  3   6
2022-05-24T15:14:49+0000    57  13  7
2022-05-24T12:25:35+0000    43  8   2
2022-05-24T11:15:24+0000    66  7   2
2022-05-24T10:45:56+0000    38  15  2
2022-05-23T17:51:09+0000    59  7   1
2022-05-23T17:50:44+0000    47  6   3
2022-05-23T15:48:02+0000    127 7   13
```

[image: Table Definition]

If you look at the 16th row it has the same date as the first row but the number of PostLikes are different (92 and 96) PostComments and PostShares also change. I want to create a stored procedure where when I input the date it will return the difference. For example, if I select the third row with date 2022-05-25T13:05:27+0000 it should give the result:

```
DateT                           PostLikes        PostComments        PostShares
2022-05-25T13:05:27+0000            7                  1                 10
```

Now one method of doing this is:

```
select max(PostLikes) - min(PostLikes) as LikeDifference, max(PostComments) - min(PostComments) as CommentDifference, max(PostShares) - min(PostShares) as ShareDifference
from kpitb.userLikes
where DateT =  "2022-05-25T17:31:34+0000";
```

But this method is only good if there are two values, the database is going to have several values with the same dates. (Note DateT is VARCHAR)
For e.g.

```
Row 1  2022-05-25T13:05:27+0000     24
Row 2  2022-05-25T13:05:27+0000     34
Row 3  2022-05-25T13:05:27+0000     67
```

How to find the difference.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you just do your same max(PostLikes) - min(PostLikes) logic, but use a GROUP BY on the Date field, and a WHERE condition that filters on the parameter passed in?

Comment: It's not clear what the logic would be if you had more than 2 rows - is it the difference between the first row and the last? If so you have a problem because there is no way of establishing sequence. Please add table definition and sample data as text which we can use as opposed to images which we can't .(Also the image hurts my eyes)

Comment: FIirstly, your query is going to be much simpler, and faster, if you store the dates as `DATETIME` instead of `VARCHAR`. Secondly, exactly what do you mean by 'difference' when there are several values to handle?

Comment: @P.Salmon I've provided sample text, and table def.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Due to how the data is being entered I'm using varchar, and by difference I mean that what will the query be if there are say 10 rows of data with the same dates.

Comment: You need to tell us what you mean by difference if there are more than 2 rows - preferably with an example

Comment: @P.Salmon, I've added the example.

Comment: @FakhrAli Difference is a concept that applies to two values. I have no idea what that means when there are several values, and apparently neither do you. You need to explain exactly what calculation you want to perform with several values to give 'difference' or we're not going to be able to help you.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular, Accorsing to the example I've added if there are two values it should subtract and return the value, if there are 3 it should subtract the max value from the previous one, not the first. It should subtract 67 from 34 not 24. This is the part where I'm stumped because the dates are the same.

Comment: I could use there ID's but that would be a very long procedure.

Comment: Still not clear - are you only considering last 2 (by date and id) and discarding rows prior to last 2, and if only 1 exists? and if you are on mysql version 8 or above lag might be useful - you should state what version you are on

Comment: @P.Salmon MySql version 8. Basically yes I want to subtract the last two values ( the new one and the one prior )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using window functions you can find the max id and the previous values and the main query becomes trivial.

```
with cte as
(select t.*,
         lag(postlikes) over(partition by datet order by id) prevlikes,
         lag(postcomments) over(partition by datet order by id) prevcomments,
         lag(postshares) over(partition by datet order by id) prevshares,
         t1.maxid
from t
join (select max(id) maxid,datet from t group by datet) t1 on t1.datet = t.datet
order by datet,id
) 
select datet,
         case when prevlikes is null then postlikes else postlikes - prevlikes end likes,
       case when prevcomments is null then postcomments else postcomments - prevcomments end comments,
       case when prevshares is null then postshares else postshares - prevshares end shares
from cte
where  id = maxid;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html